# What GUI-based, open-source software options are there for configuring ZFS?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, zfs, compression

In Ubuntu, configuration of settings such as the following can be done via console as mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443593/which-file-is-used-for-the-configuration-of-zfs), including:

- Choice of compression algorithm
- Choice of the compression strength
- Enabling and disabling deduplication.

With which GUI based open source software, can one perform ZFS configurations such as the above?

Comment: I'm not aware of any open-source projects currently in development. But there is [Poolsman](https://www.poolsman.com/), which just opened for early access, but unfortunately is payware.

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar "alpha" stage plugin for [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/) that does ZFS management. Cockpit provides a general web management interface for several functions.

*I have no first-hand knowledge of this, as I haven't tested it.*

First install Cockpit with the Universe repo enabled:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cockpit
```

Then Cockpit can be accessed on the IP address of the host on port 9090 (`https://X.X.X.X:9090/`).

Then run the following commands to clone the ZFS control panel into Cockpit:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/optimans/cockpit-zfs-manager.git
$ sudo cp -r cockpit-zfs-manager/zfs /usr/share/cockpit
```

And then reload Cockpit.

After installation, the ZFS Manager plugin can be found under `ZFS`.

[image]

The Cockpit interface is a little more polished than Webmin, but its general functionality is more limited.

There is a video with a [demonstration of this Cockpit plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HEO7qXa6jo&t=745s).

The project has not been updated for several years and is officially archived, but it should still support basic ZFS functions. 
*Because of this, use at your own risk!*

Comment: This is amazing!  thank you!  looks to be out of development now

Answer (score 3):

There is an "alpha" stage module for [Webmin](https://www.webmin.com/) that does ZFS management. Webmin provides a general web management interface for many functions.

First install the Webmin PGP key and repo:

```
curl -o setup-repos.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webmin/webmin/master/setup-repos.sh
sh setup-repos.sh
```

Then install Webmin:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install webmin
```

Then Webmin can be accessed on the IP address of the host on port 10000 (`https://X.X.X.X:10000/`).

Then download the ZFS Manager Alpha 0.1.5a release:

```
wget https://github.com/jonmatifa/zfsmanager/releases/download/v0.1.5a/zfsmanager-0.1.5.wbm.gz
```

From Webmin, open `Webmin` -> `Webmin Configuration` -> `Webmin Modules`. Browse from `From local file`, and locate the file `zfsmanager-0.1.5.wbm.gz` you downloaded.

Click `Install Module`.

After installation, the ZFS Manager module can be found under `Hardware` -> `ZFS Manager`.

[image]
...
[image]

The module has 3 tabs: `ZFS Pools`, `ZFS File Systems` and `Snapshots`. Under Zpools and filesystems, you can view properties, and change them by clicking on the property and selecting its value.

The project has not been updated for several years, but it still supports many basic ZFS functions. 
*Because of this, use at your own risk!*

Answer (score 1):

ZFS Administration GUI

"Zyggy is a very simple GUI for basic ZFS administration. The system provides graphical access for most frequently used ZFS and ZPOOL commands, as listed below:

Commands available to date:

```
zfs create (Dataset)
zfs create -v (Volumes)
zfs rename
zfs snapshot
zfs clone
zfs promote
zfs rollback
zfs remove
zfs get all
zpool rename
zpool remove
zpool get all"
```

Install:

```
sudo apt install zfsutils-linux
```

Download and extract zyggy from:

```
https://github.com/manoeldesouza/zyggy
```

Run:

```
sudo ./zyggy
```

Source:
https://github.com/manoeldesouza/zyggy

Be carefull, its looks like pre alpha or so on.

Comment: But I don't think this tool supports setting the `compression` and `dedup` properties you asked about.

Comment: @Artur Meinild, The mentioned functions are only examples of a long list of functions of a ZFS management tool. It even displays the compression algorithm.

Comment: Ah ok cool - I didn't know that. I was aware of the tool, but didn't know what it could actually do. 

Answer (score 0):

No GUI is yet available for the follow Canonical ZFS Management software, but it is assumed that this will be done as well as a Gnome integration.

According to the following article, Zsys is intended to be Canonical's managent software:

- https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-de.en.8ed37788-6391dadf-66f3e5ca-74722d776562/https/www.techrepublic.com/article/something-exciting-is-coming-with-ubuntu-19-10/

A presentation of Zsys and his options can be found in the following source:

- https://didrocks.fr/2020/06/02/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20.04-lts-zsys-commands-for-state-management/

The Github project and download page is:

- https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys

Answer (score 0):

"ZFS Commander is a simple front-end for the most commonly used zpool & zfs commands. While the tool is a work-in-progress, several functions are already working. See the list of functions implemented in Usage section.

The tool is composed of 2 panes, each showing different ZFS related information. The tool will start with Datasets at left and Snapshots at the right pane. By pressing TAB, each window will cycle through the different modes: Pools, Datasets, Volumes and Snapshots."

Source and Download:

- https://github.com/manoeldesouza/zc